# Allow only admin can delete submitted record

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

my scenario is once users submit a record(parent record), they cannot delete/edit the child record as well. Only the admin can edit or delete. The problem with this code is, they also not allow admin to do so. May I know how to solve this?

```
trigger preventDelete on Child__c(before delete) {
    
    Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
    String profileName=[Select Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;
    
    Set < ID > testentry = New Set < ID > ();
    
    for (Child__c tst: trigger.old) {
        testentry.add(tst.Parent__c );
    }
    
    set<id> mdrRecord = new map<id,Parent__c>([Select Id From Parent__c Where (Approval_Status__c= 'pending' OR Approval_Status__c LIKE '%Approved by%') and Id IN: testentry]).keyset();
    
    for (Child__c record : trigger.old){
        if (profileName !='System Administrator ' || profileName !='Marketing Admin' ){
            
            If(mdrRecord.contains(record.Parent__c)){
                record.addError('This record is locked. If you need to delete it, contact your admin.');
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (profileName !='System Administrator ' || profileName !='Marketing Admin' ){
```

This condition always evaluates to `true` because any given Profile name is always either not equal to System Administrator (note the spurious space in your comparison) or not equal to Marketing Admin.

You *could* fix this by changing the `||` to `&&`, but it would be better instead to use a Custom Permission. Create a Custom Permission (say `My_Custom_Delete_Permission`).  Then, set the Custom Permission on the Profiles you wish to allow deletion for or grant it to specific users via a Permission Set. Check for it using the [`FeatureManagement`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_FeatureManagement.htm) class:

```apex
if (!FeatureManagement.checkPermission('My_Custom_Delete_Permission')) {
```